# Highlight different items in an HTML table using CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td >Old</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>New</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Is there any technique I can use to highlight the items that have changed ( in this case , 2nd row's 1st column) using CSS ? or do I have to resort to other things like JavaScript ?

Comment: you need to add javascript for this

Comment: You need to use JS with an onchange event

Comment: if you're using Javascript anyway (ie to change the content) then why not just change the class of the item at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 .highlight{
    background: fuchsia;
}
</style>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr class="highlight">
<td >Old</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>New</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

And if something changes you can add the class to the specific element:

```
$(element).addClass('highlight');
```

or with plain JavaScript:

```
element.class = 'highlight';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to highlight the second column of the second row specifically this will work:

`table > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color:#FFEEEE;
    }`

If you're asking how to highlight changed rows ANYWHERE, use a class.

Add this to the  of your document or the stylesheet.

`<style> .highlight { background-color:#FFEEEE; }`

Add this to your TD's

`class="highlight"`

Comment: He needs to highlight if something changes

Comment: use `>` instead of spaces between the selectors, to avoid affecting nested tables.